# error blinks when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i made a sign up form in which if you keep name or last name input it shows a error written byside of the input i did the same in radio input.every thing is working but,the problem is 
when the submit button is clicked the errors blinks and go away. the button type is submit 
i am writting the code down

```
function SignUp() {
var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
var lastname = $("#lastname").text();
var date = $("#dd option:selected").text();
var month = $("#mm option:selected").text();
var yy = $("#yy option:selected").text();
var sex = $("input:radio[name=sex]:checked").val();
     if ($.trim($("#firstname").val()) == "") {
    document.getElementById("firstnameerror").innerHTML = "Please write firstname";



    if ($.trim($("#lastname").val()) == "") {
    document.getElementById("lastnameerror").innerHTML = "Please write lastname";



    if (!$("input[name='sex']:checked").val()){
    document.getElementById("gendererror").innerHTML = "Please select your gender";

       }

    }
      }
 }
```

Comment: put it on fiddle or add your Html code.

Comment: adding it to html code doesn't work and what is fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ - can put your code here.

Comment: i just did but it is showing man errors but,there were no error in chrome console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `SignUp()` function as your submit button is clicked you must `return false` for the form to not be submitted.

With jquery you could easily do:

```
$('#submitButtonId').click(function(){

 SignUp();
 return false;

})
```

If all goes right after the javascript validation you could do:

`$(#myFormId).submit();`

Or just plain:

```
<input type="submit" name="send" value="SEND" onclick="SignUp(); return false;" />
```

Comment: silly question but where to write $(#myFormId).submit();

Comment: i have cleared my question there is one more thing to be added just use
else method like this 
if ($.trim($("#lastname").val()) == "") {
        $("#lastnameerror").text("Please write lastname");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        $("#lastnameerror").text("");
    }

`

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you don't prevent default behavior of the form which is submiting. Try this (simplified code):

```
function SignUp(e) {
    var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
    var lastname = $("#lastname").text();

    if ($.trim($("#firstname").val()) == "") {
        $("#firstnameerror").text("Please write firstname");
        e.preventDefault(); // <!-- prevent form submit in case of errors
    }
    else {
        $("#firstnameerror").text('');
    }

    if ($.trim($("#lastname").val()) == "") {
        $("#lastnameerror").text("Please write lastname");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        $("#lastnameerror").text("");
    }
}

$('#form').submit(SignUp)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fh6Ar/

Also don't bind *click* events to submit buttons. Form has special event for this `submit event`.